# Hidden Field Element with value as number always return string

Tags: javascript, html

Consider the following code:
HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" value=3 name="hello" id="test"/>
<input type="button" value="test me!" onclick="checkType();" />
```

JS:

```
function checkType(){
    var num = document.getElementById("test").value;
    alert(typeof num + ": " + num);

}
```

Or see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0h61xwkg/2/).

As you can observe, i placed a number for the value attribute of the HTML hidden element. 
I researched about the matter not find anything but to use typeof function to show what kind of data type the thing im lookin at is.

I dont know if it was valid as well anyway, placing an un-qouted number in the value attribute.

But the thing i want to accomplish is, store a number hidden away from the UI, and then take it back and correctly show it as number back to the screen..

Been searching for about 3 days now, and rubber ducking* hasnt had any effect at all by now.
And No JS gurus here in my office.

Best regards,

Comment: All input values are strings. Whatever value you assign it will be converted to a string.

Comment: convert it back to to an integer. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: hi sirs, do you have any idea how can i make things dynamic converting things to int when they are int, otherwise as string. used typeof function just to fail

Comment: Presumably you should know which values should be numbers and which should be strings. Therefore you should apply this knowledge to your code.

Comment: Use parseInt(document.getElementById("test").value,10) for integers or parseFloat( document.getElementById("test").value) for decimal values - noe the casing of the commands.

Comment: managed to do it. if i used the "+" unary operator, it returns "NaN". From there i would be able to know dynamically which are numbers and which are strings! Thanks @OrionMelt

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As p.s.w.g said, input values are strings. If you really want to convert it to Number type, just use the unary + operator.

```
var num = +document.getElementById("test").value;
```

Updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/0h61xwkg/3/

Comment: do you have any idea how can i dynamically test if the value inside the hidden field is a number or just a string?

Comment: @LeeJeong You could use a regular expression for that before converting it to a number. `/^\d+$/` if you are only concerned with integers. If you wanted to test for floating point numbers it is a little more complicated `/^\d*\.\d+$|^\d+\.\d*$/`.

Comment: For the other readers that might stumble: If you want to know whether a value is number or string from the attribute value of hidden element (or whatever element i guess), use "+" unary operator. It returns "NaN" when used with strings and returns number if otherwise. Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0h61xwkg/5/

Comment: Please note that the unary operator returns `0` instead of `NaN` for empty string.